# Exporting Animation from Blender to C4D

Tags: animation

I hope you are doing well! I am reaching out to all the C4D/Blender GURU's for help on a specific matter that I cannot find on Google...

How do I export this animation? As a vdb? I've tried .fbx. and alembic but they aren't transferring to C4D.... I can't find anything online about how to take a project like this with all these shaders and nodes and now animation, and turn it into vdb files so that I can then load that vdb into my render's volume option... any advice?

(I somehow managed to make this after 6 attempts lmfaooo)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XWv1Ajc3tfU&list=LL&index=3

but now I don't know how to get the vdb... I wanted to import it into my scene in C4D and render everything with the render engine, Arnold, that I have.... Do you know how to get vdb from something like this? If not, I can just make it work in after effects and export as png sequence (found another tutorial for Blender animation render stuff) but I'd really really like to use the Arnold engine and this work flow would be perfect if I could get passed this hurdle...

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please don't write in all caps in the title or body of any posts, it is the written equivalent of shouting, is [harder to read](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_caps#Readability) and may be [considered rude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_caps#Computing). Please use the [edit] button below the post to change you text into regular case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use geonodes to build geometry, you need to place a "Realize Instances" node at the end so that the mesh "exists" instead of being virtual. Then you can export as alembic.

That being said, you will probably not be able to export the material anywhere. Anything beyond a Principled BSDF with bitmaps is pretty much not exportable.